# Binding a list property to crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a data object that contain fields with many datatypes one of this is dictionary, when I add this object as a datasorce fo a crystal report, the dictinary filed is not added to the field explorer with the crystal report editor. How can I add the properties that are of a list or dictionary types to a crystal report?

---

To be more specific, the custom object I want to bint to a crystal report is similar to the following:

```
public class MyClass
{
 Publuc MyClass()
 {
  this.Services = new Dictionary`<string,decimal`> ();
  }
  public string Name{set;get;}
  public string Address{set;get;}
  public Dictionary`<string,decimal`> Services{set;get;}
}
```

What I want is to be able to display the services dictionary with in the crystal report, for now I can only bind the simple properties like the Name and Address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I actualy did to solve this problem is, I used a data set with two tables "MyClass" table that has the same properties except for the dictionary and "Service" table that has two properties, then I bounded the data set to the crystal report and now I can have access to both tables with the crystal report designer.